# viewWillDisappear is not called

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewwillappear, linphone

I'm using a navigationController in my app. One UI i have tried to click one button (Not in Navigation bar) viewWillDisappear is not called. But i'm not using the navigationController it's calling the viewWillDisappear. Can you please help me how to call the viewWillDisappear with a navigationController?

Comment: viewWillDisappear gets called on all view... even with navigationController too

Comment: do you know when viewWillDisappear will get occurred?

Comment: Should use NavigationController's delegate method instead to track push and pop

Comment: @fahim Praker: When i added navigationController

Comment: @ user1256663 i have used .. wait i will share my code here

Comment: @user1256663: Can you please send example . I clicking the button is normal its not a navigation item

Comment: @user1256663: please help me i want you help

Comment: How did you trigger the viewWillDisappear when not using NavigationController? Please share some code that you've tried.

Comment: - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [viewController viewDidAppear:animated];
}

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "linphone"? Is that relevant to the problem?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
     self.navigationController.delegate = self; }

Comment: @MartinR: I'm using this for customizing the linphone

Comment: @user1256663: Can you please connect tv i will show my code its possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826876/linphone-android-how-to-import-the-library-project any idea's plz?

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` is a method specific to `UIViewController` class.

Second, this method shouldn't be called directly from the code, this method is called automatically when a `UIViewController` is removed from a view hierarchy. [(check UIViewController specs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear%3a))

So in order to handle this method call, you have to implement it in your custom `UIViewController` class (do not forget to call `[super viewWillDisappear:animated]`). Whenever your custom `UIViewController` view will disappear from the screen (is popped from the stack or other `UIViewController` is added to the stack) this method will be called.

Comment: it use for normal button also?

Comment: @2vision2 I don't understand your question. Like I said the method will be called only on a `UIViewController` not on `UIView`, every time the `UIViewController`'s view is removed from the screen.

Comment: can you connect with team viewer i will show my issue. Can you please