# Linphone Android how to import the library project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, linphone

I am working on SIP application and using Linphone Library.
I am trying to make and run the build on the device but getting few issues

I have setup the Android SDK and NDK set up on my Mac.
Now when i copy the repo via Terminal using command

```
$ git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive
```

And than to Makefile ran this code:

```
$make
```

[image]
and Then it show's Build Successfull.

Now i need to import this project into Eclipse and when i do this imported project (folder named "linphone-adroid") into my Eclipse it shows me alot's of projects i am confused which one should i use and if i choose all of them then it gives me lot's of errors in other's (Shown in image below)

liblinphone-android --> Ran this on Device runs fine but when i call the numbers it changes it's view and shows duration 0:00 and does not calls the numbers then i have to press hang off button to dismiss the call. (Not able to make call's)

[image]

Please suggest me how should i import this project into my eclipse and what else scripts i need to run on the terminal to make it run.
So far what i have did is right or wrong?

Comment: Hi, Please help me to compile latest linphone for android on Ubuntu. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after building the library you have to import it in eclipse
File -> New -> Other... -> Android -> Android Project from Existing Code -> Browse_your_project

Now open your application (Project which have activity) and assign linphone library which you have earlier loaded....
Right click on your project -> select Android tab from left hand side -> from the bottom library section, click on "Add..." -> you will see the listed library which you have in your eclipse workspace -> select correct one -> click "OK" -> now refresh and clean the project -> build and try to run

Comment: you have library project not .jar file right ?
correct me if anything wrong in my understanding...

Comment: I have not loaded the linphone library in eclipse earlier my eclipse ..eclipse is totally blank ...  i have gsm.jar file

Comment: I don't see any listed library when i go under Android tab and in library section it gives blank window no lib to select....which library i have to select and how?

Comment: i have edited your answer with the whole solution. (kindly accept my edit so i can accept your answer)... thx for helping

Comment: answer is sufficient to resolve the issue....
I know there is some minor mistake because you have started to learn Android....still.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , it worked finally.
After build using "make" command.I installed in my device using "make install". Also generated sdk using "make linphone-sdk"
And then simply imported in eclispe just like normal android project.
Without any error it worked. - thank god.

In windows8 cygwin created many issues, so i did build the code using "make" command in MAC. And then simply imported in windows eclipse. (some admin permission issue in MAC)
Note: android-ndk-R9c was failed my build. So then i tried with android-ndk-R9 without additional toolchain it worked great. Android-ndk old versions available at
(http://page2rss.com/0dc3a880ab1762303011d69d18408917).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this about a thousand times! I had such a hard time getting linphone to import in either Eclipse or Android Studio. Making the SDKs did it for me. For what it's worth, it seems like the command has changed in newer versions. I ran the following before import: `make`, `make liblinphone-android-sdk`, and `make mediastreamer2-sdk`. The last two steps are listed as "Optional" on the [readme](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android).

Answer (score 1):

check complete guide on [linphone android](http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html) on coders hub.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @bhavana 
I was doing wrong while importing the linphone-android project into my eclipse.
The correct process is explained below-

Importing into Eclipse :
After i have made the build then now i just need to import the project into eclipse.

**Step1**:  Go to eclipse click on File Menu then Import then select
 Existing Android Code into Workspace

Hit Next and Browse to the **linphone-android** project folder
And Only tick linohone-android folder and Leave copy project into workspace untick 
Like the below image:
 [image]

And hit finish. 
Now i right clicked on "linphone-android" (project name) and go to Properties and Java Build Path and then Order and Export and then reorder them as my image below and untick gcm.jar
[image]

Hit OK
And Boom No errors 
Now just run it on device or emulator. (Cross check minimum target SDK matches with the device or emulator.)

The above steps worked fine for me.