# Linphone Android Import and Build

Tags: android, eclipse, git, ffmpeg, linphone

I am working on Linphone Library and using [GITHUB](https://github.com/dmonakhov/linphone-android) repo and downloaded the zip file with Download Zip button.

[image]

Now when i go through the README file i saw that i need to run `./prepare_sources.sh` script then i ran it on terminal but it asks for file to patch as [image]

Now when i opened the folder inside submodules/externals/ffmpeg -- It's completely empty
and other folders are also empty. 
But on GitHub also i saw it with some kind of black folder which i can't select.
I am stuck here ? should i do how can i get all these files into my directory so that i can make the build.

One more thing Should i import this downloaded Zip into my eclipse it shows me these projects which one should i import (Should i import it after i download the Zip from Github or should i import it after running all the scripts to make the build on terminal and then import it in eclipse)?

Need Help .
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am also stuck in this same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826876/linphone-android-how-to-import-the-library-project .... plz let me know if you get it resolved

Answer (score 3):

because all this are submodules so you have to download it thru terminal

Enter Following Command then you get everything with subfolders.

git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive

--recursive will fetch submodules also.

i hope it helps you.