# How to run linphone in android studio

Tags: android, linphone, videochat, linphone-sdk

I want to integrate android video chat in my app.I am trying out linphone but they just have provided source code with no documentation and no sample modules.I imported project in android studio just to get lot of errors.I did not find any tutorial on how to run it in android studio all the tutorials are outdated using eclipse.
So,is there any link on to run linphone in android studio so that i can start to explore it.Please help

Comment: I know it's not what you want, but I was able to get it running in Eclipse by following the steps [here](http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html#.WBoyrPkrKUk) with the additional step of building the optional SDKs [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21283851/931860). I would prefer to work in Android Studio too, but Eclipse is better than nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did work for me on mac on [this](https://culinphone.wordpress.com/)

Note :- the build script tries to read a file RELEASE.txt in the root of `/ndk-bundle/`. It has been removed since >= ndk 15.

You need add a RELEASE.TXT in the root with text containing following

`r15c (64-bit)`.

Rest is all the same.